Horizontal AND Vertical Menu on WordPress Site
I haven't used WordPress in a while, but took on a new client and they want to replicate their current site (within region) which includes having some navigation on the top of the screen, and most of it on the left. I've tried several different themes and searches before posting here, and am surprised I don't already have this working. Again, it's been a minute since I worked with WordPress sites, but I thought it was very easy to add a secondary menu and put it in the sidebar. But in the latest WP Admin Console, I can't seem to find the option to turn the sidebar on.
Any and all feedback would be appreciated.
